# Processing only one out of multiple concurrent Web API requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, concurrency, locking

We are implementing a game in Android and IOS. At the end of the game, each client calls an API for finishing the game. It looks like the following:

```
/game/finish
```

along with a json like this:

```
{ GameId:1, WinnerId: 2, .... }
```

In order to make sure the Finish is always called, both players calls this Api with the same parameters. So, the requests may be received at the same time at the server. In server side, we should process only of these concurrent requests and drop the other one (in order to increase/decrease winner/loser Points correctly and some other business).

Server side is implemented using C#, WebAPI

I am thinking using lock statement, but it may affect performance.

Any help that gives me a better solution would be much more appreciable.

Comment: What about if only the winner sends the request?

Comment: Either make sure that only one client sends the request or mark a game as solved, when you get on API call and simply check that the game was already handled e.g. finished. (`if(!isGameHandled(gameID)){ //handle and save state }`)

Comment: So if Winner internet connection is lost at the end of the game, what happens? We will lost that game @Oscar. That 's why we force both clients to call finish

Comment: @Nasseh Create a local file flagging the game result as unsent and delete it once winner has send the request correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `lock` and there are actually many ways to do this using `lock`, the proper approach depends on many architectural questions. It can either be done at database-level, backend-level or simply at front-end (webAPI) level.
It can also be done in "lock - assign - unlock - finish" way if your game finishing process can last too long, so that the second user doesn't wait for reply too long.

You can simply use concurrent dictionary to store locks and use double-checked locking to minimize `lock`s, but some people consider it to be an anti-pattern.
In your case, the first player who submits the result will take the lock and finishes the game:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, object> _gameLocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();

// Finish process:
if (!GameIsFinished(gameId))
{    
    lock (_gameLocks.GetOrAdd(gameId, new object())
    {
        if (!GameIsFinished(gameId)) {
            FinishGame(gameId);
        }
    }
}
```

Even if the second thread passes through first check (in case of race condition), then it will wait until the first completes finishing process and then check `GameIsFinished` equal to `true` and do nothing.

I just have a couple questions to your design:

1. What if both users close the window before finishing? Is game simply ignored and forgotten?
2. What if users replace your requests with their own `winnerId` and there are two requests with the same GameId, but different `WinnerId`.
3. What if I just spam your server with different results of games which have actually never been played?

**Your server should definitely decide who is a winner**, not clients.

Comment: Here Are the answers:
1. There is a policy if one player leaves the game, the second player is winner.
2. You are right, they can. But we are a team, and I am sure both clients, set the winner correctly
3. No answer for this :)

We are using Socket IO for real time gaming and server side is nodeJS. We could not handle that in nodeJs, because we are new to it

Comment: "crossing finger solutions" (Possible, but I am sure it will never happen) are root of all evil. But this answer shows also such a solution: Hopefully noone will raise the worker process count

Comment: I should mention each player is Authenticated first when submitting the result (calling Finish Api)